# In a disconnected DBContext with small DBSets, does distinguishing an entity's State between Unchanged and Modified really matter?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Maybe I'm still getting used to the idea of manually adding State tracking to my disconnected DBContext EF implementation. But I wonder if it really matters when distinguishing between the State of Unchanged and Modified for an entity when the size of the DBSet is small. Tracking Added and Deleted is pretty easy. But:

Will it really impact my performance if I simply register all but Added or Deleted entities as Modified in a disconnected context? When I SaveChanges I would just accept that each entity would be subjected to an Update rather than being passed over if truly unchanged. Will I really loose that much?

If distinguishing between Unchanged and Modified really does matter, and manually modifying the code to perform State tracking is less than simple(especially with Database First where the code can be overwritten), why go disconnected? Should I just leave the context open and let the ChangeTracker do its thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it matters. Suppose you have two users, and both users open the window / web page / whatever to modify data. User 1 modifies entity 1. User 2 modifies entity 2. User 1 saves the data. User 2 saves the data. Do you really want user 2 to silently overwrite user 1's data? It's bad enough when it's the same entity, but at least in that case there is an explanation for why it works like that. Here, data would be overwritten that user 2 didn't even *want* to save.

Now, the question of whether you should keep your context around, or create a new one to save the changes in, is more difficult to answer. Ideally, yes, keep your context around and use EF's built-in change tracking, but depending on the application, you may not know when the context is safe to dispose of, and there is a performance cost to change tracking. The latter is usually negligible, so I would not worry about that until you get concrete problems, but the former is a real problem for web applications, especially web applications with long-lived sessions and non-standard session stores. Whether it will be a problem for you is something you will need to measure and/or decide for yourself.

Comment: Hehe, it's a matter of perspective. In synchronised swimming, for instance, 14 seconds apart wouldn't count as even close to perfect :)

Answer (score 2):

The main issue with not distinguishing between `Unchanged` and `Modified` is if you have **concurrent access** to the data store:

- say you get a graph of entities from the store and you send them to the client (disconnect)
- the client only modifies a single entity E, changing property A
- meanwhile another client has updated entity E, changing property B
- later you get E back and you proceed to synchronization
- if you mark the whole entity as modified EF will generate a **full update** and you will **reset the change** made by the other client

So unless you have **concurrency tracking** you will lose some changes!